# Requested unknown parameter error in JQuery Datatable MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'am working on datatable and facing this error

DataTables warning: table id=DataGridTable - Requested unknown parameter 'TranID' for row 0, column 0.

Other says that my table column defines in HTML doesn't match with the columns received from server. BUT in my case both are same.

Please help! Thank you!

Controller:

```
public IActionResult CompanyProfileView(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        CompanyProfileModel objCompanyProfileModel = new CompanyProfileModel();

        string strResXML = "";
        string strErrMsg = "";

        try
        {
            objCompanyProfileModel.CompanyProfileView(ref strResXML, ref strErrMsg);
            if (strErrMsg != "") throw (new ApplicationException(strErrMsg));

            TextReader sr = new StringReader(strResXML);
            XElement root = XElement.Load(sr);

            IEnumerable<XElement> allRecords =
               from el in root.Elements("RESULT_ROW")
               select el;

            IEnumerable<XElement> filteredRecords = allRecords;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
            {
                filteredRecords = from el in allRecords
                                .Where(el =>
                                       el.Element("TranID").Value.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()) ||
                                       el.Element("CompanyID").Value.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()) ||
                                       el.Element("CompanyNm").Value.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()) ||
                                       el.Element("CompanySubNm").Value.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()) ||
                                       el.Element("CompType").Value.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()))
                                  select el;
            }

            var displayedRecords = filteredRecords
                                .Skip(param.iDisplayStart)
                                .Take(param.iDisplayLength);

            var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["iSortCol_0"]);
            Func<XElement, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 0 ? (c.Element("TranID") != null) ? c.Element("TranID").Value.ToString() : "" :
                                                            sortColumnIndex == 1 ? (c.Element("CompanyID") != null) ? c.Element("CompanyID").Value.ToString() : "" :
                                                            sortColumnIndex == 2 ? (c.Element("CompanyNm") != null) ? c.Element("Purpose").Value.ToString() : "" :
                                                            sortColumnIndex == 3 ? (c.Element("CompanySubNm") != null) ? c.Element("CompanySubNm").Value.ToString() : "" :
                                                            (c.Element("CompType") != null) ? c.Element("CompType").Value.ToString() : "");
            var sortDirection = Request.Form["sSortDir_0"]; // asc or desc
            if (sortDirection == "asc")
                displayedRecords = displayedRecords.OrderBy(orderingFunction);
            else
                displayedRecords = displayedRecords.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);

            var result = from c in displayedRecords
                 select new
                 {
                    TranID = (c.Element("TranID") != null) ? c.Element("TranID").Value.ToString().Trim() : "",
                    CompanyID = (c.Element("CompanyID") != null) ? c.Element("CompanyID").Value.ToString().Trim() : "",
                    CompanyNm = (c.Element("CompanyNm") != null) ? c.Element("CompanyNm").Value.ToString().Trim() : "",
                    CompanySubNm = (c.Element("CompanySubNm") != null) ? c.Element("CompanySubNm").Value.ToString().Trim() : "",
                    CompType = (c.Element("CompType") != null) ? c.Element("CompType").Value.ToString() : "", 
                    Action = "Action",
                 };



            return Json(new
            {
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = allRecords.Count(),
                iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredRecords.Count(),
                aaData = result
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                sMsg = e.Message,
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = 0,
                iTotalDisplayRecords = 0,
                aaData = ""
            });
        }
    }
```

Ajax:

```
$('#DataGridTable').dataTable({ 
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource": "/DataGrid/CompanyProfileView", 
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            $.ajax({
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "POST",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData, 
                "success": fnCallback  
            });
        },
        "aoColumnDefs" : [ 
             { sTitle  : "TRANSACTION ID", sType : "string", mData : "TranID",       aTargets: [0], sClass  : 'centered-cell' },   
             { sTitle  : "COMPANY ID",     sType : "string", mData : "CompanyID",    aTargets: [1], sClass  : 'centered-cell', sDefaultContent: "" }, 
             { sTitle  : "COMPANY NAME",   sType : "string", mData : "CompanyNm",    aTargets: [2], sClass  : 'centered-cell', sDefaultContent: "" }, 
             { sTitle  : "SUB NAME",       sType : "string", mData : "CompanySubNm", aTargets: [3], sClass  : 'centered-cell', sDefaultContent: "" }, 
             { sTitle  : "COMPANY TYPE",   sType : "string", mData : "CompType",     aTargets: [4], sClass  : 'centered-cell', sDefaultContent: "" }, 
             { sTitle  : "ACTION",         sType : "string", mData : "Action",       aTargets: [5], sClass  : 'centered-cell', sDefaultContent: "" },
        ],  
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            $('td:eq(5)', nRow).html('<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" ><img src=\"/dist/img/edit.png\" width=\"20px\" height=\"20px\"/></button>&nbsp;<button class=\"btn btn-danger btn-xs\" ><img src=\"/dist/img/delete.png\" width=\"20px\" height=\"20px\"/></button>');
         }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<table id="DataGridTable" class="display">  
                            <thead>  
                                <tr>  
                                    <th class="gridheader" style="text-align:center">TRANSACTION ID</th>  
                                    <th class="gridheader" style="text-align:center">COMPANY ID</th>  
                                    <th class="gridheader" style="text-align:center">COMPANY NAME</th>  
                                    <th class="gridheader" style="text-align:center">SUB NAME</th>  
                                    <th class="gridheader" style="text-align:center">COMPANY TYPE</th> 
                                    <th class="gridheader" style="text-align:center">ACTION</th>
                                </tr>  
                            </thead> 
                            <tbody></tbody> 
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the actual response and I got this:

```
{
"sEcho": "1",
"iTotalRecords": 2,
"iTotalDisplayRecords": 2,
"aaData": [
    {
        "tranID": "1000-12102017-000001",
        "companyID": "COMP1",
        "companyNm": "SAMPLE",
        "companySubNm": "",
        "compType": "SCHOOL",
        "action": "Action"
    },
    {
        "tranID": "1000-12102017-000002",
        "companyID": "COMP2",
        "companyNm": "SAMPLE COMPANY",
        "companySubNm": "",
        "compType": "COMPANY",
        "action": "Action"
    }
]
```

}

I just changed the mData

```
mData : "TranID", to mData : "tranID",
```

and it works...